# Addint textview to tableview dynamically

Tags: android

I want to populate the android tableview's rows with an array at runtime...
How to go about it....please advise

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can populate table view row's by reading tables child as follows:

```
TableLayout x = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table_id);
for(int i=0;i<x.getChildCount();i++){
   TableRow tr = (TableRow) x.getChildAt(index);
   //Do here with table row, what u want to do.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TableLayout layout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
TableRow tr = new TableRow(context);

TextView view = new TextView(context);
view.setText("Test");
tr.addView(view);
layout.addView(tr);
```

Comment: @ Vladimir. You are adding textview direct in tablelayout. It doesnt make sense. You must have new tablerow first and then add textview into that and that table row will go into tablelayout